# > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:DebugCompileClasspath

Tags: java, android

Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:DebugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :.....
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :......: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
>   Could not resolve project :retrofitlib.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :retrofitlib: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: post the gradle.

Comment: same problem I have here